# Is there an R function to find P-values and standard deviation for finite mixture modeling

Tags: r, logistic-regression, standard-deviation, significance

I have a question about finding P-values and standard deviations in R for finite mixture modeling. I have used the mixtools package (logisregmixEM) for a research. From there I got corresponding components with their coefficients, shown below:

```
dput(head(out.3.1$beta))
```

```
-113.554228089564, 85.8568239333594, 69.529811815757, 2.04122936030937, 
-0.224133734059534, 0.187941094390128, 0.341071906324811, -0.3432506594164, 
-0.00731884252474948, 0.878493908098931, 0.0337483330433497, 
0.423255572216283, -0.022725911109589, -0.169046203073331, -0.00796170326778525
), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("beta.0", "beta.1", "beta.2", 
"beta.3", "beta.4", "beta.5"), c("comp.1", "comp.2", "comp.3"
)))
```

Is there any way to find out if the beta's I got are significant, and is there a way to find out the standard deviations, both for each component. In the mixtools package, they don't speak about any standard deviation or significance/p-values. Hope you can help me out!

Comment: The EM algorithm doesn't really result in a variance co-variance matrix. If I remember correctly, the EM algorithm shares many similarities with Bayesian methods. In fact, `logisregmixEM` does return the full matrix of posteriors for each observation.

Comment: I indeed have the full matrix of posterior probabilities, but how could the posterior matrix help me for result? I don't think it adds interpretational power for variables. or am I wrong? But, how do you think the posterior matrix would help me? @edsandorf

Comment: If you want the standard errors, I believe the most straight forward would be to use bootstrapping. I do not know if the package comes with a bootstrapping function built in. If not, you could always write your own, or try to use one of the many bootstrapping libraries available (although I cannot vouch for any of them in this context).